# How to use pthread_mutex_trylock?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

Using trylock:

```
FILE           *fp;
pthread_mutex_t demoMutex;

void * printHello (void* threadId)
{
    pthread_mutex_trylock (&demoMutex);

    pthread_t      writeToFile = pthread_self ();
    unsigned short iterate;
    for (iterate = 0; iterate < 10000; iterate++)
    {
        fprintf (fp, " %d ",  iterate,         4);
        fprintf (fp, " %lu ", writeToFile, sizeof (pthread_t));
        fprintf (fp, "\n",     writeToFile, 1);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock (&demoMutex);
    pthread_exit (NULL);
}
```

and then main ():

```
int main ()
{
    pthread_t        arrayOfThreadId [5];
    int                  returnValue;
    unsigned int iterate;

    fp = fopen ("xyz", "w");
    pthread_mutex_init (&demoMutex, NULL);

    for (iterate = 0; iterate < 5; iterate++)
    {
        if (returnValue = pthread_create (&arrayOfThreadId [iterate],
                                    NULL,
                                    printHello,
                                    (void*) &arrayOfThreadId [iterate]) != 0)
        {
            printf ("\nerror: pthread_create failed with error number %d", returnValue);
        }
    }

    for (iterate = 0; iterate < 5; iterate++)
        pthread_join (arrayOfThreadId [iterate], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Here the output first prints some of the first thread and then the rest, and then again the first. The lock isn't working. If I replace the same with `pthread_mutex_lock` every thing gets shown very sequentially!

What's the ridiculous mistake here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It does not make sense to call `pthread_mutex_trylock()` without testing the result.

If it fails to acquire the mutex, you should *not* enter the critical section, and you should *not* unlock it later.  For example, you could rewrite it like so (note that you are also very confused about how `fprintf()` should be called):

```
void *printHello(void *threadId)
{
    if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&demoMutex) == 0)
    {
        unsigned short iterate;
        for (iterate = 0; iterate < 10000; iterate++)
        {
            fprintf (fp, " %d\n", iterate);
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock (&demoMutex);
    }

    pthread_exit (NULL);
}
```

However, it probably makes more sense to use `pthread_mutex_lock()` instead of `pthread_mutex_trylock()`, so that your thread will wait for the mutex to be available if it is contended.  `pthread_mutex_lock()` is in almost all cases what you want; the `_trylock` variant is only for optimising some unusual cases - if you ever encounter a situation where `_trylock` is needed, you'll know.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you provide an example where `..._lock()` is preferred to `..._trylock()`? Ex. if you want to implement a timeout, wouldn't `trylock` be the choice? Or does it not make sense to do a timeout?

Comment: `..._lock()` is the appropriate option in most cases because in most cases, the thread cannot make any useful forward progress without taking the mutex.  In this case, if a `...trylock()` is used and cannot take the lock, the only option is to loop around and attempt to lock it again.

Timeouts should only be required in cases where an external event is required for forward progress, which tends to map to a condition variable and hence `pthread_cond_timedwait()` can be used.  An unbounded wait on a mutex indicates a problem in the code itself rather than an exceptional condition.

Comment: Agree with the last sentence there... I've got some legacy code where the developer got a little bit too ambitious and maybe didn't understand how threading works. The code also is attempting to sleep the thread for a single millisecond at a time. You have to laugh, otherwise it makes you cry!

Answer (score 7):

```
...
while (pthread_mutex_trylock(&demoMutex) == 0)
...
```

Your code makes no sense. Where is it force locked? It's like a not working spinlock that use more CPU?!

**trylock** returns 0 when it locks, so:

```
if(!pthread_mutex_trylock(&demoMutex))
{
  // mutex locked
}
```

> The pthread_mutex_trylock() function shall return zero if a lock on
>   the mutex object referenced by mutex is acquired. Otherwise, an error
>   number is returned to indicate the error.

Answer (score 7):

caf had a great answer on how to use it. I just had to grab that explanation for myself, however I did learn that `pthread_mutex_lock()` has far more overhead in class and just tested it out using the `<time.h>` lib and the performance for my loop was significantly increased. Just adding in that two cents since he mentioned that maybe you should use `pthread_mutex_lock()` instead!

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 4
#define LOOPS 100000

int counter;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

// using pthread_mutex_lock
void* worker() {
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        counter++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// using try_lock - obviously only use one at a time
void* worker() {
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++) {
        while (pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex) != 0) {
            // wait - treated as spin lock in this example
        } 

        counter++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    clock_t begin = clock();
    pthread_t t[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;

    counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        rc = pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, worker, NULL);

        if (rc) {
            printf("Thread #%d failed\n", i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(t[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("%d\n", counter);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Time Spent: %f", time);

    return 0;   
}
```

Obviously you would comment out one worker to test it, but if you try it out, I get `Time Spent: 1.36200` as an average for `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `Time Spent: 0.36714` for `pthread_mutex_trylock()`.

Goes faster again if you use Atomics.

Comment: This answer deserve an up vote. For certain situations, you do need to use _trylock, but make sure you check the result result of the result.

Comment: I wonder if the spin lock in this case could be the cause of your performance increase? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603404/when-is-pthread-spin-lock-the-right-thing-to-use-over-e-g-a-pthread-mutex

Comment: Well it looks dangerous to me. Imagine mutex is not available in that case ur thread will use 100% CPU looping, instead of waiting like in case if mutex_lock

Answer (score 2):

The code is meant to block to ensure **mutual exclusion** where you call `pthread_mutex_trylock()`. Otherwise it is undefined behavior. Therfore you must call `pthread_mutex_lock()`.

Answer (score 2):

a modified version of force locked with while loop should be more stable.

```
void *printHello(void *threadId)

{

   while (pthread_mutex_trylock(&demoMutex) == 0)

   {

        unsigned short iterate;

        for (iterate = 0; iterate < 10000; iterate++)

        {

            fprintf (fp, " %d\n", iterate);

        }


        pthread_mutex_unlock (&demoMutex);

        break;

    }

pthread_exit (NULL);
```

}`

Answer (score 2):

The use of pthread_mutex_trylock is used to ensure that tou will not cause a race to a specific command.
In order to do so, you must use pthread_mutex_trylock as a condition! an not assume that it would work by it self.
example-
    while(pthread_mutex_trylock(&my_mutex)==0){
          printf("The mutex is in my control!!\n");
     }

that way you can be sure that even if the mutex is now locked, you are doing abusy-waiting for it in that particular thread.