# Is ISR or mutex task has the higher priority?

Tags: mutex, isr

is it possible for an ISR to occur during mutex task is running, actually what I want to  know is whether mutex task or ISR has the higher priority?

Comment: Not answerable: too broad. Can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the OS and the mutex implementation.  Typical mutex APIs contain a [`trylock()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258308/how-to-use-pthread-mutex-trylock).  There are versions of `trylock()` which can be used in an interrupt service routine (ISR).  However, as an ISR services hardware and they must always execute.  There is no way to *block* the execution with a mutex.  Instead, the hardware can be turned off so there are no interrupts or interrupts can be **masked**.  Masking the interrupts is frond upon as it will increase interrupt latency; Ie, you can cause hardware issues.

It is a really bad idea for a general user task to block all system interrupts.  If this is what you wish, you probably have an issue with your design.