# pthreads condition variable with spinlock

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

The pthreads implementation of condition variables, [pthread_cond_t](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_cond_wait.txt) uses a pthread_mutex_t as its locking mechanism.  I can't think of any reason why a pthread_spinlock_t wouldn't also work.  But because this is C and not C++ I can't just treat a spinlock like a mutex.

So my questions are:

- Is there any reason why a "condition variable" implementation couldn't use a pthread_spinlock_t instead of a pthread_mutex_t?
- Does that code exist somewhere that I could look at it and/or use it?

Comment: You mean, apart from the fact that condition variables are _defined/designed_ to be used with mutexes?

Comment: On a side note, if the underlying mutex happens to be an adaptive one, it may spin anyway, and give you the best of both worlds, sort of.

Comment: @DonalFellows, pthread_cond_t's may be defined/desgined to use mutexes.  I don't think the general concept of a condition variable requires it, but that is part of my question.

Comment: @user2719058, in my testing, a pthread_mutex_t defined with type PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP, is far slower than a spinlock for my mostly uncontested locks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the *reasons* for a condition variable not to use/pair with a spinlock are pretty much the same as the [reasons not to use spinlocks in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603404/when-is-pthread-spin-lock-the-right-thing-to-use-over-e-g-a-pthread-mutex/6605443#6605443).

If you were implementing your own condition variable, however, you could make it pair with a spinlock rather than with a mutex. There's no fundamental reason it wouldn't work.