# Does pthread_spinlock cause switch from user space to kernel space

Tags: c++, linux, locking, mutex, atomic

I've known that many things can cause switch from user space to kernel space, such as `malloc`, `ptherad_mutex_lock` etc.

My question is if the spinlock will cause the switch too or it will stay in the user space?

Furthermore, same question on `std::atomic` from C++11: `std::atomic` will stay in the user space or it needs to switch from user space to kernel space?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: @user253751  Well, I want to know the performance of `mutex`, `spinlock` and `atomic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on implementation, [`pthread_spin_lock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_spin_lock.3.html) is not officially guaranteed to remain in user-space. In practice on systems that have a CAS instruction (i.e. most commodity SMP systems) it will often be the case.

Here are the links to the glibc implementations for [x86](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/sysdeps/i386/nptl/pthread_spin_lock.S), [x86-64](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/sysdeps/x86_64/nptl/pthread_spin_lock.S), [ia64](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/sysdeps/ia64/nptl/pthread_spin_lock.c), [sparc32](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/sysdeps/sparc/sparc32/pthread_spin_lock.S), [sparc64](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/sysdeps/sparc/sparc64/pthread_spin_lock.S), [PPC](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/sysdeps/powerpc/nptl/pthread_spin_lock.c), [SH4](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/sysdeps/sh/nptl/pthread_spin_lock.c) and the [general case](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/nptl/pthread_spin_lock.c), all based on a CAS loop.

Similarly there is no guarantee that a particular `std::atomic` implementation won't go to kernel, but in practice, especially when `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free()` returns `true`, it will be implemented in user-space with the help of atomic instructions.

Note also that in modern Linux `pthread_mutex_lock` is implemented using a [`futex`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html), i.e. a "user-space mutex", it remains in user-space in non-contended case. `malloc` will go to kernel only if there's a contention or when more virtual memory needs to be reserved.

Having said that, whether or not a spin lock is the right choice for synchronization is a broader question that depends on more factors that just system calls. As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603404/when-is-pthread-spin-lock-the-right-thing-to-use-over-e-g-a-pthread-mutex), it is useful in true SMP cases, when the contended state is very short. The majority of performance benefits come from savings on context switching and scheduling.

Some mutex implementations (the Windows critical section for example) are hybrid: they will spin for a while first and only after that delegate to a syscall-based lock.

Comment: Great explanation. One more little question: Can I say that CAS instruction must be in kernel-space?

Comment: No that's not needed, the CAS instruction is just a CPU instruction, it works the same way in user-space and kernel-space.